# calling wcf service from php gives not found error

Tags: php, wcf, soap-client

I'm trying to call a WCF service from php.  When I call the php page it gets a Not found error when calling the AuthorizeCard method. I verified that the method exists by calling $client->__getFunctions ().  I thought that it might be related to the fact that the service call expects a .net ChargeDetails object with the properties defined below.  So along with trying an array of values, I also tried using the $container / stdClass() which I found on another stackoverflow answer on how to mimic a .net class.  Any ideas why I'd be getting this error or if the stdClass is the way to pass a version of the ChargeDetails class?

```
<?php
    define('NEWLINE', "<br />\n");


    class SoapClientNG extends \SoapClient{
        public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = SOAP_1_1,$one_way=0){
            $xml = explode("\r\n", parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version, 0));
            print_r($xml);
            $response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $xml[5] );
            return $response;
        }
    }

    $client = new SoapClientNG("https://www.oururl.com/api/CreditCardProcessingPhp.svc?wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => 0));

    try{
            $container = new stdClass();

            $container->request->CardExpirationDate = '06/18';
            $container->request->CardNumber = '1411111111111111';
            $container->request->CardVerificationNumber = '123';
            $container->request->ChargeAmount =  '10';
            $container->request->ChargeComment = 'Test charge';

            $card = array(
                'CardExpirationDate' => '01/18',
                'CardNumber' => '1411111111111111',
                'CardVerificationNumber' => '123',
                'ChargeAmount' => '10',
                'ChargeComment' => 'Test charge'
            );

        //$functions = $client->__getFunctions ();
        //var_dump ($functions);

        $webService = $client->AuthorizeCard($card);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        print($client->__getLastResponse());
        exit();
    }

    $client = null;
?>
```

Comment: Just because you can browse to the service page successfully does not mean the service will work.  It's possible the service is throwing an error and PHP is interpreting it as Not Found (I'm not that familiar with PHP, so it's just a guess).

Comment: Ah yes, that pointed me in the right direction.  I was thinking it was erroring just trying to connect when actually the error occurs on the method call AuthorizeCard.  Thanks.